# obtener todos los valores de un select al cargar la pagina

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

Tengo el siguiente código, resulta que quiero capturar todos los `Values` de un `Select` oculto una vez cargada la pagina en **Html**, capturarlos en **Javascript** y mandarlos por medio de un `JSON` al controlador de `laravel.

Aquí les dejo el código, muchas gracias por su ayuda:

```
            <div>
                <select name="annios[]" id="annios" hidden multiple="multiple">
                    @foreach($precebo as $fecha)
                        <option value="{{$fecha->año_destete}}">{{$fecha->año_destete}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
```

Así lo genero el array:

```
var array =$("[name='annios[]']").val();
```

creo que puede ser un error cuando lo genero.

Comment: ¿Qué problemas te estás encontrando al hacerlo? ¿Recibes algún error o algo?

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro cuando miro en consola al cargar la pagina, el array esta vacio.

Comment: ¿Cómo generas el array? Quizás haya algún problema y podemos ayudarte con eso.

Comment: asi lo genero `var array =$("[name='annios[]']").val();` creo que este debe ser mi error cuando lo genero

Comment: Ese `$` es de jQuery, ¿no?

Comment: claro q si, es obvio

Comment: Te falta añadir el select al selector , `$("select[name='annios[]']").val();` pero , ¿porqué hacer eso y no obtener todos directamente en el controlador a donde se envía? no veo la utilidad de enviar un array de un controlador a la vista y luego de la vista los mismos datos a otro controlador o ruta. _( a menos que se me escape algo que no está en la pregunta)_

Comment: @JuanEstebanYarce Sí y no. Yo lo asumí al poner la etiqueta, pero jQuery no es la única biblioteca que usa el alias `$` (por eso existe el método [noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/))

Comment: @Dev.Joel de hecho tengo que hacerlo asi por que la otra forma que se me ocurrio era mandarlos quemados y asi no me serviria

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro la verdad no sabia que otras libreiras aparte de `juery` utilizaban el alias `$`

Comment: ¿Como así ,  quemados? ¿a que se refiere ?  ¿Como los necesita en el controlador ? ,  podría haber obtenido los id del array de esta forma `$array= Model::pluck('id');` para una colección , para un array solo le añade el `->toArray()`    y ya sin necesidad de hacer todo ese proceso innecesario :)

Comment: Ahora estoy en el móvil y no puedo responder, pero para lo que quieres puedes usar `each` para rellenar un array vacío de inicio. Cuando llegue a un ordenador te pongo una respuesta si nadie te responde antes.

Comment: @Dev.Joel suena raro en verdad pero necesito obtenerlos desde `javascript`

Comment: Creo que de las nuevas ninguna, pero hasta no hace mucho era un pequeño problema si se usaban varias al mismo tiempo, creo que mootools era una si no recuerdo mal.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que `.val()` te va a devolver sólo el valor seleccionado del `select` (o en su defecto el del primer `option`) pero no un array de valores de los `option`. Además, tal y como se está haciendo sólo se selecciona el `select` y no los `option`.

Lo que podrías hacer es seleccionar todos los `option`, recorrerlos usando `each` y guardar sus valores en un array. Algo como esto:

```js
var miArray = [];

$("[name='annios[]'] option").each(function() {
  miArray.push($(this).val());
}); 

console.log(miArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <select name="annios[]" id="annios" hidden multiple="multiple">
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Función generalizada, para un uso más amplio.

```js
function current__select__values(id) {
 const e = document.getElementById(id);
 return Array.apply(null,Array(e.options.length)).
 map((cur, i, arr) => {
  return arr[i] = {
            selectName: e.options[i].text,
            selectValue: e.options[i].value
            };
 });
}

var data = current__select__values("f"); // Datos guardados aquí
    console.log(data);
```

```html
<select id="f">
<option value="H4"> 4 Hamburgesas </option>
<option value="B9"> 9 Bebidas </option>
</select>
```